# How to set up different reply-to addresses for different emails, in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I email a bunch of different clients from the same Gmail account. I am also using Zoho Projects to manage all of them. Zoho provides a feature that allows you to directly email areas of your project and see the email text appear under a task, a document, etc.

If I am emailing client A from Gmail, I would like to set the reply-to address such that when the client replies, it goes straight into my Zoho Projects task.

When I email Client B, I want the reply-to address to be different that for Client A.

Is there a way to set this up without going into the Setting->Account and Import every single time I email? Obviously, that would be completely inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reply from your other accounts you will need to add the each reply-to addresses/accounts through [Accounts and Imports](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370) one time (not every time you reply), which you access through
**Settings >> Accounts and Imports**.

In the **Send mail as** section you click on '*Add another email address you own*', enter the name and email address for your desired email account, and follow through with gmail's verification process- which requires that you have access/own the other email account.

Once you have this set up you will be able to reply from the account/address of your choosing by expanding the email header section of your reply (by default it's condensed) and changing your **From** address via dropdown:

> If you're replying to or forwarding a message, click the field where
>   your recipients are listed, then click **From**. After clicking **From**,
>   you'll see a drop-down menu next to your address, where you can select
>   the email address you'd like to send from.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I simply want to add a bunch of "reply-to" addresses with each one corresponding to a specific client. I might have 100 clients and Google will not allow to set up 100 accounts I own.

Comment: @Imray your best bet would probably be to use a mail client application to do that.